# Why is the "Encrypted" format not available in the list when erasing a USB flash chip in Disk Utility?

Tags: macos, disk-utility, filevault

It shows up for normal, external hard disk drives. Is there a way I can force it to encrypt?

The installed OS X is El Capitan.

Comment: I'm not sure why it doesn't offer before format [but it doesn't, you're right], however, you can encrypt it at any time afterwards - this answer gives a good explanation - http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/181105/85275

Comment: Thank-you. I turned your comment in to a simple answer below.

Answer (score 6):

You can't do it from Disk Utility but you can do it from Finder by right-clicking on the partition and choosing Encrypt.

1. Open Disk Utility and click on the drive (not the partition)
2. Click Erase button
3. Choose Name
4. Choose Format: OS X Extended (Journaled)
5. Choose Scheme: GUID Partition Map
6. Click Erase button
7. When complete, open Finder
8. Right-click on the new drive partition
9. Select Encrypt
10. Enter passwords
11. Finish

Comment: The key step here is "click on the drive (not the partition)".  (by the way, I did it from Disk Utility.)

Comment: For me, after step 10 I get "A partition, not a whole disk, is required for this operation." Could not find any way to create a partition -- the Partition button is greyed out. I also tried Erasing to select the encrypted format -- but that option does not appear

Comment: Under Big Sur, when I try this, the volume format gets changed to APFS (Encrypted).

Comment: This converts the format to APFS.

Answer (score 6):

1. Open Disk Utility
2. In the top left of the Window, select the *View* drop down
3. Select *Show All Devices*
4. Click on the top level external drive (Note in the image below in the sidebar how the parent device is selected)
5. Press the *Erase* button and set the *Scheme* to *GUID Partition Map*

At this point, the Format option will contain the encryption options:

[image]

Comment: I can not get these steps to work in Big Sur. Encrypted doesn't appear for Mac OS Extended.

Answer (score 4):

For newer versions of Mac OS (Big Sur and onward), Mac OS Extended (Journaled, Encrypted) is no longer an option. If you erase it unencrypted and then use Disk Utility to encrypt, it gets converted to an APFS file system.

Previously, I would always use Mac OS Extended (Journaled, Encrypted) for Time Machine backups. Big Sur added Time Machine support for APFS (Encrypted).