# How to encrypt USB drive on a Mac?

Tags: usb, encryption

I have an external USB drive and want to encrypt it. I have seen many 'suggestions' on how to do that, but I do not see any option to encrypt the drive. I am using MacOS 10.13.2.

I have see, for example, [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/220765/why-is-the-encrypted-format-not-available-in-the-list-when-erasing-a-usb-flash). But in step 9, when I right click the drive (on the Desktop or the Finder), there is no option 'encrypt'. Before that I have formatted the drive in the 'Mac OC Extended (Journaled)' format. No option for encryption in the `Disk Utility` either ...

So how to do that? Maybe the option was forgotten in the new OS version?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find a way to do this from Disk Utility, but you can accomplish it from Terminal using `diskutil`.

Open Terminal and run `diskutil list` to show all devices currently connected. One of the entries should look similar to

```
/dev/disk7 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *1.0 GB     disk7
   1:                  Apple_HFS LOGBOOK                 1.0 GB     disk7s1
```

with the name of your USB stick instead of `LOGBOOK`. Take note of the device shown in the first line.

Then run

```
diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ NEWNAME GPT /dev/diskWHATEVER-NUMBER-YOURS-IS
```

to **erase all content** and create the required partition scheme. Replace `NEWNAME` with whatever name you want to use (enclose in `""` if it contains anything else than letters) and use the device number found above.

Once done you can encrypt in Finder by right-clicking on the stick name in the sidebar.