# Pause External Disk Encryption

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, encryption

I have a large external drive that I would like to encrypt using my laptop.  Based on the size of the drive, I believe the encryption will take several days.  I would really like to be able to unplug and move my laptop during this time, which would thus necessitate a way to pause the encryption process.  Answers such as [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/300829/encrypt-external-usb-thumb-drive-on-macos-high-sierra?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) give good procedures for the encryption, but do not mention pausing.  `man diskutil` does not seem to mention anything about pausing, nor can I find any options for it when using the OSX GUI.

I am quite wary about just ejecting the drive during the encryption process (though it is a new drive so I wouldn't actually lose data).  Is there any way to pause the encryption process?