# Disk encryption format for external drives that works on both macos and linux

Tags: ntfs, exfat, macos, hfs+, encryption

Is there any disk encryption scheme or format that can be used on both macos *and* linux?

Linux cannot read Apple's [drive encryption](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/301855/66812) format, and [LUKS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Unified_Key_Setup) is not supported on MacOS.

I tried using [VeraCrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr) encrypted partitions in exFat format and it mounted successfully several times on MacOS but after a system update exFat mounting of veracrypt volumes does not work anymore (no issues on linux). Also, exFat does not seem to be a reliable file system, so I searched for alternatives, but apart from **fat32**, **exFat** and **ntfs** I don't see any viable alternatives for a reliable cross-platform file system.

All of these formats have issues: **fat32** has file size limits, **exfat** veracrypt partitions are not mountable on macos, and **ntfs** is proprietary, linux support is not reliable, and veracrypt does not support it on linux/mac. `hfsplus` works fine on mac but is read-only on linux. I hoped to be able to use `ext3/ext4` with veracrypt encryption but even though I have fuse with `ext4fuse` working in read-only mode working for unencrypted drives veracrypt is apparently not able to interoperate with fuse drivers.

Fat32 would be a great option since it works well with veracrypt on any OS, but the file size limitation and lack of symlinks is simply not acceptable.

Any other options I might have missed?

Answer (score 2):

Veracrypt+exFat works on Mac/Linux/Windows. The problems with mounting on MacOS were caused by configuring veracrypt encryption for the entire disk rather than a single partition. As a result the partition table was encrypted too. While this worked fine on linux it caused problems on MacOS. Creating a normal unencrypted partition table with an exFat partition and then encrypting that partition with veracrypt works fine cross-platform.

The downside is that Apple's exFat driver does not always cleanly unmount the partition which in turn unconditionally triggers `exfatfsck` on the next mount attempt and that can take hours to finish for large size disks.