# What is currently a good way to format and encrypt an external drive so that it's usable on both Mac and Linux?

Tags: external-disk, encryption

I've looked at the threads on this, noting that there doesn't appear to be any new discussion since 2019.

I would like to be able to encrypt an external drive, but still have it readable across multiple operating systems. I think I can probably ignore DOS (which I actually still use), since DOS support for USB is spotty at best. WinDoze is a "maybe" at best.

Would exFAT be a good choice of format?

The general consensus from prior discussions (e.g., [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/355994/331833)) seems to be that VeraCrypt would be a good choice of encryption, but I'm puzzled: do I need to have VeraCrypt installed on a box, in order to mount the encrypted drive on that box?

Comment: I don't think anything has changed since the old question and answer you have linked.

Comment: @Gilby Ok, but I'm still wondering whether I need to have VeraCrypt installed on a box, in order to access the drive, or if the drive is self-contained. With very little WinDoze and Linux left in the office, it might make more sense to use an Apple-proprietary format and Apple encryption.

Comment: You do need to install VeraCrypt. But, there may be other solutions to what is behind your specific technology question.